# react native can't run iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

react native can't run iOS,I have to configure the environment in accordance with the official website of the method, but has been unable to run

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxNjo.jpg)

[Run time results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI9ct.jpg)

Comment: just press the reload command. it could be that the simulator ran before the packager

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Shut the Terminal spawned by React Native.
2. Shut down XCode completely
3. Re-open everything and re-run.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Close the terminal packer
2. Stop Xcode from debugging
3. Close the Google Chrome tab that has been spawned for debugging purposes
4. Restart Xcode debugging using the Play button

OR

By navigating to your React Native project folder, run:

```
npm start
```